# Sum of sparse matrices - Matlab numerical error

Tags: sum, sparse-matrix, zero, numerical

I have the following problem:

```
N=500; 
A = sparse(1:500,10*ones(N,1),0.005*ones(N,1),N,N); 
A(:,300) = -0.005*ones(N,1); 
>> sum(A,2) 
   ans = All zero sparse: 500-by-1 
B = spdiags(0.45*ones(N,1),0,N,N); 
B(:,34) = -0.45*ones(N,1); 
B(34,34) = 0; 
>> sum(B,2) 
   ans = All zero sparse: 500-by-1 
C = A+B; 
>>max(sum(C,2)) 
     ans = (1,1) 4.3368e-18.
```

Since the sum of the rows of A and B is 0, the sum of the rows of C should be 0 too. But for large sparse matrices, this is not always the case. Even if it is e-18, I need it to be closer to 0.

How can I make matlab improve precision in this kind of computations?

Thank you

Comment: Please give a reproducible example of your problem/code.

Comment: N=500;
A = sparse(1:500,10*ones(N,1),0.005*ones(N,1),N,N);
A(:,300) = -0.005*ones(N,1);
>> sum(A,2)
ans =
   All zero sparse: 500-by-1

B = spdiags(0.45*ones(N,1),0,N,N);
B(:,34) = -0.45*ones(N,1);
B(34,34) = 0;
>> sum(B,2)
ans =
   All zero sparse: 500-by-1
>> C = A+B;
>>max(sum(C,2))
ans =
   (1,1)      4.3368e-18.                             Since the sum of the rows of A and B is 0, the sum of the rows of C should be 0 too. But for large sparse matrices, this is not always the case. Even if it is e-18, I need it to be closer to 0.

Comment: You should edit your question with that information for readability.